# php look for new line in a varible and insert <br>

Tags: php, regex

i have a varible like so:

```
$Text= "Hello 
        My 
        Code"
```

so what i want to happen is where ever there is a new line to insert 
 so it should look like

```
$NewText = "Hello<br>
            My<br> 
            Code"
```

*

Comment: have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php), [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) or [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$text = "Hello\nMy\nCode";

$newText = nl2br($text);

$newText = preg_replace('/\r?\n/', "<br>\n", $text);

$newText = str_replace("\n", "<br>\n", $text);
```